# Django: Django generated sql query causes error

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.1

**Updated question:**

Django is giving me the following sql query:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = %s  args=('andrew',);
```

If I execute the sql query in the postgresql command line, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ..." FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = %s  args=(...
                                                             ^
```

However, when I slightly modify the statement, then I get the cirrect result from postgresql.

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = 'andrew';
```

**Is the Django generated query incorrect?**

---

Hi Stackoverflow people,

Very simple code which drives me crazy:

I want to extract the user information from user_auth with

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk = request.user.pk)
```

However, I get an error message in Django:

```
'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

When I check the sql query and execute it in the psql command line, psql gives me also an error message, which makes me thinking that the statement might be incorrect.

psql statement is:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = %s ; args=(7,)
```

**Why does it say %s in the WHERE statement? The user id is not a string.**

I believe the solution must be very simple - but I can figure out what the issue is here.
Thank you for your help and suggestions!

**Additional explanation**

I am using the django_social_auth package for the user authentification. The user will be directed to the dashboard site once the 3rd part cleared the credentials, therefore I would assume that request.user is not None.

**Complete traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://login.test.com:8000/profile/dashboard/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'guardian',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'userena',
 'userena.contrib.umessages',
 'south',
 'django_extensions',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'social_auth',
 'djangoratings',
 'about',
 'apps.profiles',
 'apps.map',
 'apps.contact',
 ]
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/Users/neurix/Development/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/test/test/apps/profiles/views.py" in dashboard
  35.     extra_context['username'] = user.username

Exception Type: TypeError at /profile/dashboard/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

views.py

```
...
31: print "user: %s" %(request.user.pk)
32: user = get_object_or_404(User, pk = request.user.pk)
33:
34: 
35: extra_context['username'] = user.username
36: if user.first_name:
37:     extra_context['name'] = user.first_name
...
```

---

Comment: `%s` is a generic placeholder and does not indicate a string. Try posting a traceback.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Trace back added. Thank you for your help!

Comment: And now we need to see the code containing `/Users/neurix/Development/test/test/apps/profiles/views.py:35`.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I have added the lines around line 35.

Comment: the answer is really simple: extra_context was not existing. I have added "if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()" to the code and it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that request.user is None?

```
if request.user is not None:
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk = request.user.pk)
```